# Select query by type wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

Table1

```
Code, desc, type id

01    Rajan    1
01    Sajan    1
01    Vijayan  2
01    Suresh   3
01    Caresh   4
01    Sujesh   4
01    vikran   4
02    desk     1
02    card     2
02    villa    2
02    megash   2
02    supan    3
....
```

I want to view the table by type id wise

Expected Output

```
Code type-1 type-2 type-3 type-4

01   Rajan  Vijayan suresh caresh
01   Sajan  null    null   Sujan
01   null   null    null   vikran
02   desk   card    supan  null
02   null   villa   null   null
02   null   megash  null   null
```

How to make a query for the above condition

Need Query Help

Comment: Normally I'd say PIVOT here but I'm not sure you can do that in this case since you're dealing with varchars instead of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off just staging your data up.  Note that I'm adding an identity row id for later.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
   drop table #test
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Numbered') IS NOT NULL
   drop table #Numbered

 CREATE TABLE #test (Code CHAR(2), [DESC] varchar(10), [type id] INT, RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1))


INSERT #test 
    VALUES ('01', 'Rajan', 1),
           ('01' ,'Sajan', 1),
           ('01' ,'Vijayan', 2),
           ('01' ,'Suresh', 3),
           ('01' ,'Caresh', 4),
           ('01' ,'Sujesh', 4),
           ('01' ,'vikran', 4),
           ('02' ,'desk', 1),
           ('02' ,'card' ,2),
           ('02' ,'villa', 2),
           ('02', 'megash', 2),
           ('02', 'supan', 3)
```

Then we create a holding area that uses that row id to calculate which row of the code each of the names should go on.

```
  CREATE TABLE #Numbered
      (
       RowNum int, Code CHAR(2), [type] VARCHAR(10), [DESC] VARCHAR(10)
       )

   INSERT #Numbered
         SELECT (select count(*) from #test where code=t1.Code AND [type id]=t1.[type id] AND  RowNumber<=t1.RowNumber),
                 code, 
                [type id], 
                [DESC]
            FROM #test t1
```

Lastly, we create a PIVOT table on the data, (done in a standard SQL 2000 way of "faking" that operator).  We then place that "PIVOT table" in a derived select that returns only the columns we want but allows us to sort on the code and rownum columns to generate the output you asked for.

```
     SELECT Code,[type-1],[type-2],[type-3],[type-4]
        FROM (Select P.Code,RowNum
                   , Min( Case When type = '1' Then [DESC] End ) As [type-1]
                   , Min( Case When type = '2' Then [DESC] End ) As [type-2]
                   , Min( Case When type = '3' Then [DESC] End ) As [type-3]
                   , Min( Case When type = '4' Then [DESC] End ) As [type-4]
                      From #Numbered As P
                        Group By P.Code,RowNum) R
        ORDER BY Code,RowNum
```

Please let me know if you want further explanation on any of this.

Comment: You query is working perfectly, i need to know how to use your query in view or store procedure, i am new to view & store procedure.  Can you tell me please.....

Comment: Because there's some intermediate processing you can't use a view.  You can wrap this entire code in a 
    CREATE PROC GetSummaryData
    AS
    (all the code I listed)

just make sure you change it to populate the first temp table with data from your actual table that contains the code,desc,type columns.

    insert #test select code,desc,type_id from yourtable

Comment: @TetonSig +1 Perfect query and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.code, t1.description, t2.description, t3.description from
(Select code, description from table where type=1) t1, 
(Select code, description from table where type=2) t2, 
(Select code, description from table where type=3) t3,
(Select code, description from table where type=4) t4
Where t1.code=t2.code and t2.code=t3.code and t3.code=t4.code and t4.code=t1.code
and t4.code=t2.code and t1.code=t3.code
```

Try this query it will not return null but will return repeated values

contact if you have any doubts

Comment: thanks, i don't want to repeat the values, It should display null values instead of repeating values...

Comment: Use case statement in the inner query  ex case type=1 then description else NULL end