# How to avoid the null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to avoid the null values...

Table1

```
ID Value1 Value2

001 Rajan  null
001 Vijayan null
001 null ravi
001 null sudeep
002 kumar null
002 null venkat
.....
```

I don't want to display null values.

Expected Output

```
 ID Value1 Value2

    001 Rajan  ravi
    001 Vijayan sudeep
    002 kumar venkat
    .....
```

How to make a query for the above condition

Need Query Help

Comment: The expected output doesn't make much sense. Please explain the logic governing it. What happens when you have a row with both `Value1` and `Value2` populated (or `null`)?

Comment: I just answered a very similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628573/select-query-by-type-wise/8628953#8628953

Comment: How do you know that `Rajan` and `ravi` belong together (and not `Rajan` and 'sudeep`) ?? After all - all of them have `ID = 001` ..... This output is not properly and deterministically defined.....

Comment: Perhaps adding the query to your post might help in seeing what could be done about fixing it to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you explain in more detail how those values from `Value1` and `Value2` columns belong together, and only if that "matching" is really deterministic, then you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT, Value1 VARCHAR(20), Value2 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @temp
        (ID, Value1, Value2)
VALUES
        (1, 'Rajan', NULL),
        (3, 'Vijayan', NULL),
        (1, NULL, 'Ravi'),
        (3, NULL, 'sudeep'),
        (2, 'kumar', NULL),
        (2, NULL, 'venkat')

SELECT DISTINCT
   ID, 
   (SELECT Value1 FROM @temp t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND Value1 IS NOT NULL) AS 'Value1',
   (SELECT Value2 FROM @temp t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND Value2 IS NOT NULL) AS 'Value2'
FROM
   @temp t
```

That would give you one row for each value of `ID`, with the non-NULL value for `Value1` and the non-null value for `Value2`.

But as your question stands right now, this approach doesn't work, since you have multiple entries for the same ID - and no explanation as to how to match the two separate values together....

So as it stands right now, I would say there is no deterministic and proper solution for your question. You need to provide more information so we can find a solution for you.

**Update:** if you would update to SQL Server **2005** or newer, you could do something like two nested CTE's - but in that case, too, you would have to define some rule / ordering as to **how** the two variants with `ID = 001` are joined together.....

Something like:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT, Value1 VARCHAR(20), Value2 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @temp
        (ID, Value1, Value2)
VALUES
        (1, 'Rajan', NULL),
        (1, 'Vijayan', NULL),
        (1, NULL, 'Ravi'),
        (1, NULL, 'sudeep'),
        (2, 'kumar', NULL),
        (2, NULL, 'venkat')

;WITH Value1CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value1,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value1) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM @temp
    WHERE Value1 IS NOT NULL
),
Value2CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value2) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM @temp
    WHERE Value2 IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
   v1.ID, 
    v1.Value1, v2.Value2
FROM
   Value1CTE v1
INNER JOIN 
    Value2CTE v2 ON v1.ID = v2.ID AND v1.RowNum = v2.RowNum
```

would give you a reproducible output of:

```
ID  Value1  Value2
1   Rajan   Ravi
1   Vijayan sudeep
2   kumar   venkat
```

This is under the assumption that given two entries with the **SAME** ID, you want to sort (`ORDER BY`) the actual values (e.g. `Rajan` before `Vijayan` and `Ravi` before `sudeep` --> there you'd join `Rajan` and `Ravi` together, as well as `Vijayan` and `sudeep`).

But again: this is in **SQL Server 2005** and newer only - no equivalent in SQL Server 2000, unforutnately.....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i1.ID, i2.Value1, i3.Value2
FROM Table1 i1, Table1 i2, Table1 i3
WHERE i1.ID = i2.ID and i1.ID = i3.ID and i2.Value1 IS NOT NULL and i3.Value2 IS NOT NULL;
```